# wget how to get OpenSSL version?

Tags: wget

How do i get which version of OpenSSL a wget was compiled with? when i do `wget --version`  i just get

```
$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.21.2 built on linux-gnu.

-cares +digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file -metalink +nls 
+ntlm +opie +psl +ssl/openssl 

Wgetrc: 
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: 
    /usr/share/locale 
Compile: 
    gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc" 
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../../src -I../lib 
    -I../../lib -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DHAVE_LIBSSL -DNDEBUG 
    -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/wget-8g5eYO/wget-1.21.2=. 
    -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects 
    -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security 
    -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall 
Link: 
    gcc -DHAVE_LIBSSL -DNDEBUG -g -O2 
    -ffile-prefix-map=/build/wget-8g5eYO/wget-1.21.2=. -flto=auto 
    -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects 
    -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security 
    -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions 
    -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
    -lpcre2-8 -luuid -lidn2 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lpsl ftp-opie.o 
    openssl.o http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a 

Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Please send bug reports and questions to <bug-wget@gnu.org>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial answer is similar to @hanshenrik but slightly more refined -

`strings /usr/bin/wget | grep -i  "OPENSSL" | less`

This will look for any text strings in wget (by default longer then 4 readable characters) and then look for OpenSSL in those strings -  The returned result was:

```
OPENSSL_init_ssl
OPENSSL_sk_num
OPENSSL_sk_value
OPENSSL_sk_pop_free
OPENSSL_3.0.0
+ssl/openssl
gcc -DHAVE_LIBSSL -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/wget-8g5eYO/wget-1.21.2=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -lpcre2-8 -luuid -lidn2 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lpsl ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a 
       --ciphers=STR           Set the priority string (GnuTLS) or cipher list string (OpenSSL) directly.
OpenSSL: unimplemented 'secure-protocol' option value %d
OpenSSL: Invalid cipher list: %s
OpenSSL: Failed set trust to partial chain
OpenSSL: Failed to allocate verification param
OpenSSL: %s
../../src/openssl.c
```

Probably a more correct, but also messier way to do this is with strace (strace traces system calls and signals, so it shows what is actually being called as the program is being run) -

```
 strace wget -q https://www.google.com 2> /dev/null  | egrep --color -i "ssl"
```

Ran the program to get an https site, and provided output of the running program - which shows more precisely what was linked to /called at the OS - in my case

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "#\n# OpenSSL example configuratio"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "ertout # insta.cert.pem\n\n[ssl_se"..., 4096) = 131
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/ssl/certs/c06d5c68.0", 0x7ffe52097df0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/ssl/certs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=16384, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/ssl/certs", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/ssl/certs/1001acf7.0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1915, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/ssl/certs/1001acf7.0", O_RDONLY) = 4
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/ssl/certs/1001acf7.1", 0x7ffe52097df0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The `--color` bit is not neccessary, but it highlights the SSL string.  I believe that this shows what "DLL" its reading, ie it appears to be linked against/using `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3`

Comment: thanks! also manged to refine the results: ```strings /usr/bin/wget | grep -i  "OPENSSL_" | grep -F .``` yields a single line: ```OPENSSL_3.0.0```

Answer (score 0):

this is NOT the proper way to check it, but i found a super-hacky way to maybe get it:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/wget | grep -i openssl_ --text
```

yields

> F"j�g� �<_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable__gmon_start___ITM_registerTMCloneTable__cxa_finalize__libc_start_mainstrcmpfputsfwrite__snprintf_chk__stack_chk_failstrlenstrncmpstrcasecmpdcgettextstrncasecmp__ctype_b_locstrndupabortgetpeernamegetsockname__errno_locationsocketsetsockoptbindmemcpystrpbrkstrduplocaltimestrftimecalloc__memcpy_chk__isoc99_sscanfpsl_str_to_utf8lowerstrrchrpsl_is_cookie_domain_acceptablepsl_lateststrchrqsortfopen64__fprintf_chkferrorfclosefputc__getdelimunlinkfgetcrewindstrtokstrtolmktime__strncat_chkstrptimestrtolllstat64strcpy__sprintf_chkacceptfnmatchstrstrsymlinkreallocchmodreadlinkmemcmpstderrexitstdinstdoutclearerrfreadmunmaprenamegetaddrinfogmtimeftello64fdopenmemsetinet_ntopfreeaddrinfogai_strerrorfilenoflockftruncate64strspnstrcspnmemchr__fdelt_chkselectmemmovememrchrfeof__vsnprintf_chk__vfprintf_chkisattytcgetpgrpsignal__printf_chkiswprintwcwidthmbrtowcmbsinitiswcntrlsprintfsetlocaletimegmgetpidsrandomstrchrnulclock_gettimesysconfclock_getresbindtextdomaingetopt_longoptargopterroptindfstat64dcngettextforkgetpassgetuidgetpwuidsetsidfreopen64strtok_rnl_langinfoperrorrecvinflateEndusleepinflateinflateInit2_secure_getenvmkostemp64fread_unlockedfsetxattr__vasprintf_chkutimeiconv_openiconviconv_close__longjmp_chkpcre2_compile_8__ctype_get_mb_cur_maxpthread_mutex_initpthread_mutex_destroybtowcpcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern_8pcre2_match_8pcre2_match_data_free_8pthread_mutex_lockpthread_mutex_unlockmmap64__sigsetjmpsetitimergroup_memberiswalnumiswctypefcntl64fseeko64lseek64__freadingfflushtowupperwcrtomb__ctype_toupper_loc__ctype_tolower_loctowlowerioctlpipeposix_spawn_file_actions_initposix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2__environposix_spawnppathconflistengzwritegzclosegzdopenmkdiruuid_unparseuuid_generatelocale_charsetidn2_lookup_u8idn2_strerroridn2_freeSSL_get_verify_resultSSL_CTX_use_certificate_fileSSL_writeSSL_set_connect_stateSSL_shutdownSSL_get_sessionSSL_CTX_newSSL_set_fdSSL_is_init_finishedSSL_CTX_set1_paramSSL_CTX_get_cert_storeSSL_readOPENSSL_init_sslSSL_CTX_set_optionsSSL_get_errorSSL_pendingSSL_CTX_set_post_handshake_authTLS_client_methodSSL_peekSSL_connectSSL_CTX_freeSSL_CTX_ctrlSSL_CTX_set_default_verify_pathsSSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_fileSSL_CTX_set_cipher_listSSL_get1_peer_certificateSSL_set_sessionSSL_CTX_set_verifySSL_newSSL_CTX_load_verify_locationsSSL_freeSSL_ctrlRAND_statusGENERAL_NAME_freeERR_peek_last_errorX509_LOOKUP_fileASN1_OCTET_STRING_freeOPENSSL_sk_numBIO_readERR_get_errori2d_X509_PUBKEYCRYPTO_mallocX509_STORE_set_flagsX509_NAME_ENTRY_get_dataa2i_IPADDRESSMD4_InitX509_verify_cert_error_stringBIO_s_memX509_get_subject_nameX509_freeBIO_freeASN1_STRING_to_UTF8DES_set_keyMD4_UpdateX509_NAME_get_text_by_NIDX509_get_issuer_nameERR_reason_error_stringBIO_number_writtenMD4_FinalASN1_STRING_cmpX509_load_crl_fileBIO_newX509_VERIFY_PARAM_newX509_get_X509_PUBKEYDES_set_odd_parityOPENSSL_sk_valueDES_ecb_encryptRAND_load_fileOPENSSL_sk_pop_freeX509_STORE_add_lookupERR_clear_errorX509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flagsASN1_STRING_lengthX509_VERIFY_PARAM_freeX509_NAME_print_exERR_error_stringX509_NAME_get_index_by_NIDCRYPTO_freeX509_NAME_get_entryX509_get_ext_d2iRAND_file_namelibpcre2-8.so.0libuuid.so.1libidn2.so.0libssl.so.3libcrypto.so.3libz.so.1libpsl.so.5libc.so.6UUID_1.0IDN2_0.0.0OPENSSL_3.0.0GLIBC_2.8GLIBC_2.28GLIBC_2.15GLIBC_2.33GLIBC_2.4GLIBC_2.17GLIBC_2.7GLIBC_2.14GLIBC_2.34GLIBC_2.11GLIBC_2.3GLIBC_2.2.5GLIBC_2.3.4

and near the end there you'll find the string `OPENSSL_3.0.0` thus i can GUESS that this wget was compiled with [OpenSSL 3.0.0](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/07/OpenSSL3.Final/)

... but i hope that a better way to check does exist